# SVG dynamic positioning and dimensions

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a web app that renders svg elements from cartesian points (lines, paths, etc) that come from a database.

I have a requirement that an end user can upload an svg file (icons) and drag the icon to fit within specific bounds of the points already defined and rendered in the app.

For example (see snippet), a user can upload the 'x' icon and drag it near the green line defined by two points, which should result in the icon being snapped and resized to the line - the upper left corner snapped to the line start point, and the width of the icon extending to the line end point. Same is true for the file icon being snapped to the red line. This is done dynamically during drag with js. I have omitted the js from the snippet to keep things simple, as I am confident that the answer lies with svg attributes and or style that I can set with js, but the svg properties/values are what I cannot pin down.

What I have tried - everything, I think. Given that I am nesting svg elements, I took the BBox values as an offset to used the x and y attributes on the icon svg element, and that moved it, but not to the start point. I also tried translate without success. I am able to move and resize, but not to the coordinates I need. I do not want to change the icon svg at all if possible, so i'd prefer to leave its viewBox as-is.

```html
<svg height="700" width="700" fill="#e6e6e6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <path d="M443.6,387.1L312.4,255.4l131.5-130c5.4-5.4,5.4-14.2,0-19.6l-37.4-37.6c-2.6-2.6-6.1-4-9.8-4c-3.7,0-7.2,1.5-9.8,4  L256,197.8L124.9,68.3c-2.6-2.6-6.1-4-9.8-4c-3.7,0-7.2,1.5-9.8,4L68,105.9c-5.4,5.4-5.4,14.2,0,19.6l131.5,130L68.4,387.1  c-2.6,2.6-4.1,6.1-4.1,9.8c0,3.7,1.4,7.2,4.1,9.8l37.4,37.6c2.7,2.7,6.2,4.1,9.8,4.1c3.5,0,7.1-1.3,9.8-4.1L256,313.1l130.7,131.1  c2.7,2.7,6.2,4.1,9.8,4.1c3.5,0,7.1-1.3,9.8-4.1l37.4-37.6c2.6-2.6,4.1-6.1,4.1-9.8C447.7,393.2,446.2,389.7,443.6,387.1z"/>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 380 511.7">
  <path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M26.18 0h221.14c3.1 0 5.85 1.51 7.56 3.84l122.88 145.08a9.27 9.27 0 0 1 2.21 6.05l.03 330.55c0 7.13-2.98 13.68-7.72 18.42l-.03.04c-4.75 4.74-11.29 7.72-18.43 7.72H26.18c-7.13 0-13.69-2.96-18.45-7.71l-.03-.04C2.97 499.22 0 492.69 0 485.52V26.18C0 19 2.95 12.46 7.68 7.72l.04-.04C12.46 2.95 19 0 26.18 0zm335.06 164.7c-134.78-5.58-134.35-17.38-129.82-134.02l.45-11.92H26.18c-2.05 0-3.91.83-5.26 2.16a7.482 7.482 0 0 0-2.16 5.26v459.34c0 2.02.84 3.88 2.18 5.23 1.36 1.35 3.22 2.19 5.24 2.19h327.64c2.01 0 3.86-.85 5.22-2.2 1.35-1.36 2.2-3.21 2.2-5.22V164.7zM250.25 27.32l-.15 4.01c-3.73 96.04-4.22 109.01 100.23 114.16L250.25 27.32z"/>
</svg>

<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="200" y2="20" stroke="green" />
<line x1="300" y1="20" x2="350" y2="20" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

**strong text**

Comment: 1. The main svg needs a viewBox attribute. 2. both the nested svg need a width and a height 3. calculate the center of the second svg element 4. establish the size you want for the X svg. 4. give the x svg the x and y of the center . 5. translate the x backward width/2 height/2

Answer (score 0):

Although there may be several ways to accomplish this, I figured out one way that I am going to move forward with. The confusion with this was primarily due to my lack of understanding of the svg viewBox and how the coordinate system works.

The key to this is defining a new viewBox value for each nested svg based on its BBox coordinates. The purpose of doing this is to frame the drawing without 'whitespace' to enable its placement at the desired coordinates. Once you have the BBox data, you can set the viewBox and do some simple math to properly set the desired height and width (both of which must be defined for the nested svg). After updating the viewBox, width, and height, you can then move the svg to the new location.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
        const svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg.a');
        svg.forEach(x => {
          setSvg(x);
        });
    });

    function setSvg(svg){
      const { xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax } = [...svg.children].reduce((acc, el) => {
            const { x, y, width, height } = el.getBBox();
            if (!acc.xMin || x < acc.xMin) acc.xMin = x;
            if (!acc.xMax || x + width > acc.xMax) acc.xMax = x + width;
            if (!acc.yMin || y < acc.yMin) acc.yMin = y;
            if (!acc.yMax || y + height > acc.yMax) acc.yMax = y + height;
            return acc;
        }, {});
        const viewbox = `${xMin} ${yMin} ${xMax - xMin} ${yMax - yMin}`;

        let newWidth = $(svg).attr('data-new-width');
        let newPosition = $(svg).attr('data-new-position');
        let newHeight = newWidth*(yMax - yMin)/(xMax - xMin);

        svg.setAttribute('width', newWidth);
        svg.setAttribute('height', newHeight);
        svg.setAttribute('x', newPosition.split(",")[0]);
        svg.setAttribute('y', newPosition.split(",")[1]);
        svg.setAttribute('viewBox', viewbox);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="700" width="700" fill="#e6e6e6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <svg class="a" data-new-width="100" data-new-position="100,20" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <path d="M443.6,387.1L312.4,255.4l131.5-130c5.4-5.4,5.4-14.2,0-19.6l-37.4-37.6c-2.6-2.6-6.1-4-9.8-4c-3.7,0-7.2,1.5-9.8,4  L256,197.8L124.9,68.3c-2.6-2.6-6.1-4-9.8-4c-3.7,0-7.2,1.5-9.8,4L68,105.9c-5.4,5.4-5.4,14.2,0,19.6l131.5,130L68.4,387.1  c-2.6,2.6-4.1,6.1-4.1,9.8c0,3.7,1.4,7.2,4.1,9.8l37.4,37.6c2.7,2.7,6.2,4.1,9.8,4.1c3.5,0,7.1-1.3,9.8-4.1L256,313.1l130.7,131.1  c2.7,2.7,6.2,4.1,9.8,4.1c3.5,0,7.1-1.3,9.8-4.1l37.4-37.6c2.6-2.6,4.1-6.1,4.1-9.8C447.7,393.2,446.2,389.7,443.6,387.1z"/>
    </svg>

    <svg class="a" data-new-width="50" data-new-position="300,20" viewBox="0 0 380 511.7">
      <path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M26.18 0h221.14c3.1 0 5.85 1.51 7.56 3.84l122.88 145.08a9.27 9.27 0 0 1 2.21 6.05l.03 330.55c0 7.13-2.98 13.68-7.72 18.42l-.03.04c-4.75 4.74-11.29 7.72-18.43 7.72H26.18c-7.13 0-13.69-2.96-18.45-7.71l-.03-.04C2.97 499.22 0 492.69 0 485.52V26.18C0 19 2.95 12.46 7.68 7.72l.04-.04C12.46 2.95 19 0 26.18 0zm335.06 164.7c-134.78-5.58-134.35-17.38-129.82-134.02l.45-11.92H26.18c-2.05 0-3.91.83-5.26 2.16a7.482 7.482 0 0 0-2.16 5.26v459.34c0 2.02.84 3.88 2.18 5.23 1.36 1.35 3.22 2.19 5.24 2.19h327.64c2.01 0 3.86-.85 5.22-2.2 1.35-1.36 2.2-3.21 2.2-5.22V164.7zM250.25 27.32l-.15 4.01c-3.73 96.04-4.22 109.01 100.23 114.16L250.25 27.32z"/>
    </svg>

    <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="200" y2="20" stroke="green" />
    <line x1="300" y1="20" x2="350" y2="20" stroke="red" />
  </svg>
```